# Passing data from firestore to object?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am using this pdf plugin. I've tried putting future builder in the addPage part but it's not working. I also tried creating a function to get data but I don't know where to put it. I'm just a beginner in flutter. Thanks for the help

```
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:pdf/pdf.dart';
import 'package:pdf/widgets.dart' as pw;
import 'data.dart';

Future<Uint8List> generateInvoice(
    PdfPageFormat pageFormat, CustomData data) async {
  String customerName;

  final invoice = Invoices(
    customerName: customerName,
  );

  return await invoice.buildPdf(pageFormat);
}

class Invoices {
  Invoices({
    this.customerName,
  });

  final String customerName;

  Future<Uint8List> buildPdf(PdfPageFormat pageFormat) async {
    // Create a PDF document.
    final doc = pw.Document();
    final _image =
        (await rootBundle.load('assets/covertitle3.png')).buffer.asUint8List();

    print(customerName);
    doc.addPage(
      pw.MultiPage(
        build: (context) => [
          pw.Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: pw.MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              crossAxisAlignment: pw.CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                // buildReliable(invoice),
                pw.Container(
                    child: pw.Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: pw.MainAxisAlignment.start,
                        crossAxisAlignment: pw.CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                      pw.Text("Reliable Food Dist.",
                          style: pw.TextStyle(fontWeight: pw.FontWeight.bold)),
                      pw.Text("28 Lawrence St."),
                      pw.Text("Spring Valley, NY 10977 US "),
                      pw.Text("917-293-3854"),
                      pw.Text('info@reliablefooddist.com'),
                      pw.Text(customerName)
                    ])),
                pw.Image(pw.MemoryImage(_image), width: 200, height: 100),
              ]),
          pw.SizedBox(height: 20),
          pw.Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: pw.MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              crossAxisAlignment: pw.CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                // buildReliable(invoice),
                pw.Text('INVOICE',
                    style: pw.TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: pw.FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 20)),
                pw.SizedBox(height: 20),

                pw.Text('BILL TO',
                    style: pw.TextStyle(fontWeight: pw.FontWeight.bold)),
              ]),
          // pw.SizedBox(height: 20),
          // // _contentTable(context),
          // pw.SizedBox(height: 20),
          // _contentFooter(context),
          // pw.SizedBox(height: 20),
          // _termsAndConditions(context),
        ],
      ),
    );

    // Return the PDF file content
    return doc.save();
  }
}
```

I want to pass the field custName into the

```
final invoice = Invoices(
    customerName: customerName,
  );
```

This is my firestore.
[FIRESTORE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gdFYB.png)

Comment: FutureBuilder will not work in addPage. You need to fetch the data first, and pass them to `generateInvoice` as parameters.

Comment: How to do that sir? I'm trying all I know but I cant do it.